# скорость работы java дебаггера падает

Tags: java

При дебаггинге неокторого приложения его скорость по непонятной причине падает после рестарта.Поясню.
Имеется неокоторый бэкэнд на *jboss* сервере. Когда ставлю на дебаг, то работа приложения нормальная, брэйкпоинт достигается быстро. После стопа и старта дебаггера, первый брэйкпоинт тепер ьприходится ждать намного дольше.
Может быть это спецификой дебаггера , а не приложения?

Comment: конечно может. При использовании отладчика, jvm отключает часть оптимизаций, которые происходят в рантайме. Плюс, приходиться для отладчика собирать разную информацию (значения переменных, стектрейсы и тому подобное).

Comment: @KoVadim а когда отключил дебагер, а потом заново его включаешь. видимо какая-то информация затерается

Comment: @KoVadim посоветуйте литературы по отладчику(какие изменения в байткод вносит, какие типы брейкпоинта бывают и.т.)

Comment: я не на столько хорошо знаю и люблю java. Поэтому, мой совет простой - можете, используйте другие языки:)